# How do I use select option object values for calculations?

Tags: javascript

I have a conceptual question. What I am trying to do is have items be selectable from a
dropdown menu.

In this example, let us assume two inputs. Then, I want to call an `onClick` function to add the two values and display them somewhere. If I store all of the dropdown items in objects.

How do I populate the select options with the objects and have the values they contain be usable for math?

For instance, take this object:

```
let rifle = { 
     craftTime: 60,
     reqMats: 100
}
```

How do I use those values from a select option?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just add them as data-attributes to the options in the select?

Comment: You can have multiple data attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. You could use `data-` attributes

```
<select>
<option data-craftTime="60" data-reqMats="100">Blah</<option>
...
</select>
```

and in your change handler or whatever

```js
var option = theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex];
if (option) {
    // use option.dataSet.craftTime and option.dataSet.reqMats
    // or option.getAttribute("data-craftTime") on old browsers
}
```

### 2. Or a pattern in your value

```html
<select>
<option value="60-100">Blah</<option>
...
</select>
```

and

```js
var value = theSelect.value.split("-");
if (value.length == 2) {
    // use value[0] and value[1]
}
```

### 3. Or an index into an array of values

```
<select>
<option value="2">Blah</<option>
...
</select>
```

and

```js
// One time
var items = [
    /*something*/,
    /*something*/,
    rifle,
    /*something*/,
};

// In your handler
var item = items[theSelect.value];
if (item) {
    // use item.craftTime and item.reqMats
}
```

Comment: You mean `<option>`?

Comment: Could you expand on the last one a little? I don't understand that one.

Comment: @DecipherMePlease - you use the value of the option as an index into the items array, then use the properties from that object.

Comment: How is that array created?

Comment: @DecipherMePlease - you create it

Comment: Thanks for the help.